# Flutter: Image.file(File(path)) does not refresh the image after errorBuilder using pickImage

Tags: flutter, image, dart

My app let the user to pick an image from gallery and save it to a folder that I created before, then save the path of that image to the database, and when I enter to the page of my application I have a function to read the path from the database and then I use that path to display the image using `Image.file(File(path))` every thing works fine but if the user delete the image by accident from the folder I got an exception so I just use `errorBuilder` to show the user that image not found. The problem is when I pick the image after the `errorBuilder` shown the image does not refresh until I exit the page and return to it while when there is no image and when I pick the image its change directly.

picker function:

```
  Future _pickerLogo() async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File imageFile = File(image!.path);
    imageName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    localImage = await imageFile.copy('${f.imageAppDir}/$imageName');
   setState(() {
      print(localImage);
      dbPath = localImage.toString();
      cleanPath = dbPath.replaceAll("File: '", "").replaceAll("'", "");
      dbPath = cleanPath;
      print('cleanPath when picker $cleanPath');
      print('dbpath when picker $dbPath');
    });
  }
```

Image.file:

```
                 Container(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    child: dbPath != ''
                        ? Image.file(
                            File(dbPath),
                            errorBuilder: imageNotExist,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )
                        : Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
                  ),
```

errorBuilder Widget:

```
  Widget imageNotExist(context, exception, stackTrack) {
    print('exception: $context');
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        Text(
          AppLocal.loc.imageNotExist,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and found that if I select another image the `Image.file` refreshed the widget, so I did an if statement that if the name of image exist in database then I change the database path which is `dbPath` and its not working unless I put it in `setState`.

```
Future _pickerLogo() async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File imageFile = File(image!.path);
    imageName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    //solution begin here
    if (path.basename(imageFile.path) == path.basename(dbPath)) {
      print('dbPath : $dbPath');
      setState(() {
        dbPath = '1';
      });
      print('dbPath : $dbPath');
    } else {
      print('not exist');
    }
    //end solution
    localImage = await imageFile.copy('${f.imageAppDir}/$imageName');

    setState(() {
      print(localImage);
      dbPath = localImage.toString();
      cleanPath = dbPath.replaceAll("File: '", "").replaceAll("'", "");
      dbPath = cleanPath;
      print('cleanPath when picker $cleanPath');
      print('dbpath when picker $dbPath');
    });
  }
```